# Aligning all text to the right besides the first child

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align all navigation links, besides the logo, to the right side of the container/navigation. I want to keep 1rem margin on both sides so that the content has some space to breathe.

I've tried using the code below but nothing on the page changes:

```
.menu:not(:first-child){
  text-align: right;
}
```

```
<body>
  <div class="body-wrap">
    <header class="header">
      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="home-link"><a href="#"><img src="https://www.nicolefenton.com/_/images/dec/circle-menu.svg" height="12" width="12" alt=""></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Writing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Speaking</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
* { box-sizing: inherit; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  min-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #222222;
  border: 30px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: #f8f7f3;
}

.body-wrap {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: box;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.83rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
}

.menu:not(:first-child){
  text-align: right;
}

li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I expect all the nav links to align to the right when using the `:not(:first-child) selector.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
.menu:not(:first-child)
```

selects class menu items that aren't a first child.

What you want is:

```
.menu :not(:first-child)
```

which selects non-first-child elements within a .menu class.

Notice the space.

Or better yet, make it more obvious what you really mean:

```
.menu li:not(:first-child)
```

Comment: Thanks, Ray! That worked. Shouldn't the first selector also work, though? I do want to select all class menu items that aren't the first child.

Comment: @cklein23, the first one selected the "ul", not the "li". and that's not what you wanted.  But even if it were, it would still be wrong because the "ul" actually _is_ a first child.  So nothing ended up being selected.

Answer (score 0):

You might just have to change to this if all you are looking to do is align the text to the right.

```
.menu li:not(:first-child){
  text-align: right;
}
```